# String processing for every record in SQL Server and C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this table `Components`:

```
ItemNo  ItemDescription                Type
  1     Apple Fruit 20Kg               null
  2     Carrot Veg  1Kg                null
  3     Fig DryFruit 100g              null
```

The requirement is that, for every `ItemDescription`, I determine if its `Fruit` or `DryFruit`, I insert the value `fruit` in to column `Type`. If its type is `Veg` then I put the value `Vegetable` in to the column `Type`.

The resultant table looks like this:

```
ItemNo  ItemDescription                Type
  1     Apple Fruit 20Kg               Fruit
  2     Carrot Veg  1Kg                Vegetable
  3     Fig DryFruit 100g              Fruit
```

How do I achieve this ?

With C# code:

```
var itemDescription = GetAllItemDescription() //Executes  'select ItemDescription from Components;' SQL query
itemDescription.ForEach(item=>{
     if(item.Contains("Fruit") || item.Contains("DryFruit"))
     {
        EnterFruitInTypeColumn() //contains sql query which does the corresponding stuff.
     }
    ........
}
```

The question is:

How should I do the same stuff using only SQL statements ?

(I also know that there are T-SQL [string processing stuffs](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258891%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), but could not match any with the above requirement)

Comment: @bryanmac: Nice catch! But, I am 100% sure that this will not happen. Either it can be `Refreshing Vegetable drink` or `Refreshing fruit dring` but not both. (I am responsible for inserting data in to the table, and thats why I am sure). But, that's a nice catch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the other answers, this should get you there:

```
UPDATE Components
SET [Type] = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('DryFruit', ItemDescription) > 0 THEN 'Fruit'
                  WHEN CHARINDEX('Veg', ItemDescription) > 0 THEN 'Vegetable'
                  WHEN CHARINDEX('Fruit', ItemDescription) > 0 THEN 'Fruit'
                  ELSE null
             END
```

Answer (score 1):

The following query would do.

```
UPDATE Components 
SET [TYPE] = 'FRUIT'
WHERE ItemDescription LIKE '%Fruit%'
```

You have to rewrite the query for all types.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
update Components
set [Type]=(case when charindex('Fruit', ItemDescription,0)>0 then 'Fruit'
            else 'Vegetable' end)
```